# How to Install plug-in in Phonegap

Tags: android, ios, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

I am new in phone-gap and work on one Application which work on Android and IOS.
Now,  My requirement is that I want to send email with attachment, so i search over Internet and found This plugin, [EmailComposer-phonegap-plugin](https://github.com/GalCohen/EmailComposer-phonegap-plugin). they write there 4 point as below.

1. Add the EmailComposer.h EmailComposer.m files to your Plugins Folder.
2. Place the EmailComposer.js file somewhere in your www folder, and include it from your HTML.
3. Add to config.xml under plugins: or, if using the new format,

   ```
   <feature name="EmailComposer"> <param name="ios-package" value="EmailComposer" /> </feature>
   ```
4. On android, in the value attribute be sure to include the package name as well, for example

   ```
   value="org.apache.cordova.EmailComposer"
   ```

Now my query is how to use this plugin ?
I Done 2nd Point, but don't know where I place files as point 1? because I don't know where is my "Plug-in" folder. and how to work with point 3 and 4 ?

I also Find this code over internet. but "Attach file" alert not working.

```
var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage').value
alert("Send Mail");
window.plugins.emailComposer.showEmailComposer(
        "Send Images",
        smallImage,
        ["test@email.com",],
        [],
        [],
        true,
        ["image.jpeg", "file.zip"],
        alert("Attach file");
    );
    alert("Send Mail Success");
```

So, what I have to do for send attached mail success ?

Comment: Have installed  cord-ova plugin ...

Comment: @ManetiVinay I add cordova's jar file and add it to build path and also add its js file

Comment: you want is where to place the plugin in android and ios..

Comment: @ManetiVinay Yes. in which folder of project ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this Its work for me ...

index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />

            <title>Hello World</title>
        </head>
        <body>

            <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/EmailComposer.js"></script>  

             <script type="text/javascript">            
             document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
                function onDeviceReady() {


                            cordova.require('cordova/plugin/emailcomposer').showEmailComposer(
                                function() { console.log( 'successfully called email composer' ); },
                                function() { console.log( 'failed to call email composer' ); },
                                "Look at this photo",
                                "Take a look at this:",
                                 ["amitd.prajapati@test.com"],
                                 [],
                                 [],
                                false,
                                ["/mnt/sdcard/amit/amit.png","/mnt/sdcard/amit/amit.png","/mnt/sdcard/amit/amit.png","/mnt/sdcard/amit/amit.png","/mnt/sdcard/amit/amit.png"]
                            );
                        }

             </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

EmailComposer.js

```
    cordova.define("cordova/plugin/emailcomposer", function(require, exports, module) {
        var exec = require('cordova/exec');

        var EmailComposer = function() {
            this.resultCallback = null; // Function
        };

        EmailComposer.ComposeResultType = {
            Cancelled:0,
            Saved:1,
            Sent:2,
            Failed:3,
            NotSent:4
        }


        // showEmailComposer : all args optional
        EmailComposer.prototype.showEmailComposer = function(successCallback,failureCallback,subject,body,toRecipients,ccRecipients,bccRecipients,bIsHTML,attachments) {
        console.log("showEmailComposer()");
        var args = {};
        if(toRecipients)
            args.toRecipients = toRecipients;
        if(ccRecipients)
            args.ccRecipients = ccRecipients;
        if(bccRecipients)
            args.bccRecipients = bccRecipients;
        if(subject)
            args.subject = subject;
        if(body)
            args.body = body;
        if(bIsHTML)
            args.bIsHTML = bIsHTML;
        if(attachments)
            args.attachments = attachments;

        cordova.exec(successCallback, failureCallback, "EmailComposer", "showEmailComposer", [args]);
    }


        var emailcomposer = new EmailComposer();
        module.exports = emailcomposer;
    });
```

EmailComposer.java

```
    package com.inic.emailattacher.emailcomposser;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
    import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
    import org.apache.cordova.LOG;
    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.text.Html;


    public class EmailComposer extends CordovaPlugin {

       @Override
       public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
           if ("showEmailComposer".equals(action)) {

               try {
                   JSONObject parameters = args.getJSONObject(0);
                   if (parameters != null) {
                       sendEmail(parameters);
                   }
               } catch (Exception e) {

               }
               callbackContext.success();
               return true;
           }
           return false;  // Returning false results in a "MethodNotFound" error.
       }

       private void sendEmail(JSONObject parameters) {

           final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);

           //String callback = parameters.getString("callback");

           boolean isHTML = false;
           try {
               isHTML = parameters.getBoolean("bIsHTML");          
           } catch (Exception e) {
               LOG.e("EmailComposer", "Error handling isHTML param: " + e.toString());
           }

           if (isHTML) {
               emailIntent.setType("text/html");
           } else {
               emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
           }

           // setting subject
           try {
               String subject = parameters.getString("subject");
               if (subject != null && subject.length() > 0) {
                   emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
               }
           } catch (Exception e) {
               LOG.e("EmailComposer", "Error handling subject param: " + e.toString());
           }

           // setting body
           try {
               String body = parameters.getString("body");
               if (body != null && body.length() > 0) {
                   if (isHTML) {                                       
                       String bodyHtml = Html.fromHtml(body).toString();
                       LOG.e("EmailComposer", "Creating HTML email with body: " + bodyHtml);
                       ArrayList<String> extra_text = new ArrayList<String>();
                       extra_text.add(bodyHtml);
                       emailIntent.putStringArrayListExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, extra_text);
                   } else {
                       LOG.e("EmailComposer", "Creating text email with body: " + body);
                       ArrayList<String> extra_text = new ArrayList<String>();
                       extra_text.add(body);
                       emailIntent.putStringArrayListExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, extra_text);
                   }
               }
           } catch (Exception e) {
               LOG.e("EmailComposer", "Error handling body param: " + e.toString());
           }

           // setting TO recipients
           try {
               JSONArray toRecipients = parameters.getJSONArray("toRecipients");
               if (toRecipients != null && toRecipients.length() > 0) {
                   String[] to = new String[toRecipients.length()];
                   for (int i=0; i<toRecipients.length(); i++) {
                       to[i] = toRecipients.getString(i);
                   }
                   emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
               }
           } catch (Exception e) {
               LOG.e("EmailComposer", "Error handling toRecipients param: " + e.toString());
           }

           // setting CC recipients
           try {
               JSONArray ccRecipients = parameters.getJSONArray("ccRecipients");
               if (ccRecipients != null && ccRecipients.length() > 0) {
                   String[] cc = new String[ccRecipients.length()];
                   for (int i=0; i<ccRecipients.length(); i++) {
                       cc[i] = ccRecipients.getString(i);
                   }
                   emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_CC, cc);
               }
           } catch (Exception e) {
               LOG.e("EmailComposer", "Error handling ccRecipients param: " + e.toString());
           }

           // setting BCC recipients
           try {
               JSONArray bccRecipients = parameters.getJSONArray("bccRecipients");
               if (bccRecipients != null && bccRecipients.length() > 0) {
                   String[] bcc = new String[bccRecipients.length()];
                   for (int i=0; i<bccRecipients.length(); i++) {
                       bcc[i] = bccRecipients.getString(i);
                   }
                   emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_BCC, bcc);
               }
           } catch (Exception e) {
               LOG.e("EmailComposer", "Error handling bccRecipients param: " + e.toString());
           }

           // setting attachments
           try {
               JSONArray attachments = parameters.getJSONArray("attachments");
               if (attachments != null && attachments.length() > 0) {
                   ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
                   //convert from paths to Android friendly Parcelable Uri's
                   for (int i=0; i<attachments.length(); i++) {
                       try {
                           File file = new File(attachments.getString(i));
                           if (file.exists()) {
                               Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                               uris.add(uri);
                           }
                       } catch (Exception e) {
                           LOG.e("EmailComposer", "Error adding an attachment: " + e.toString());
                       }
                   }
                   if (uris.size() > 0) {
                       emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
                   }
               }
           } catch (Exception e) {
               LOG.e("EmailComposer", "Error handling attachments param: " + e.toString());
           }

           this.cordova.startActivityForResult(this, emailIntent, 0);
       }

       @Override
       public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
           // TODO handle callback
           super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
           LOG.e("EmailComposer", "ResultCode: " + resultCode);
           // IT DOESN'T SEEM TO HANDLE RESULT CODES
       }

    }
```

res->xml->config.xml

```
 <feature name="EmailComposer">
    <param name="android-package" value="com.inic.emailattacher.emailcomposser.EmailComposer" />
</feature>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: hmm, This sounds good. Let me try and check. and one more Question. I capture snap and display on this id "smallImage", what to do, If i want to attach that in my email ?

Comment: and where I place "EmailComposer.java" file ?

Comment: crate new package like i am create "com.inic.emailattacher.emailcomposser" and there i have EmailComposer.java

Comment: As I wrote above, I am newbe in this. This is good for me if you tech me how to create new package and use. you can also add me on skype

Comment: It shows an error "The import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext cannot be resolved", "The import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin cannot be resolved" and "The import org.apache.cordova.LOG cannot be resolved" in import section

Comment: remove those three line.